# Linear Unconditional X-Y, Non-Linear Conditional X-Y

Tags: linear, nonlinear, predictor, nonlinearity, linearity

Intuitively, I can imagine that an unconditional (i.e., unadjusted for any covariates) Y~X relation can present as a linear relation, whereas a conditional Y~X|Z relation can present as a non-linear relation.

I'm trying to prove this to myself via simulation, and am wondering if anyone might have any insight.

I'm imagining the following relations between three covariates (which I think should suffice):

1. Z ~ E1
2. X ~ Z + E2
3. Y ~ Z + X + E3

(Ei being error terms)

I'm just wondering if anyone can shed some insight as to how I might generate data that yield relations such that Y~X appears linear, Y~X|Z appears non-linear.

Apologies for any ambiguity.